# Do different types of missiles indicate different lock tones to the pilot?

Tags: military, missiles, missile-lock

Are there different lock tones for different types of missiles, e.g. [air-to-ground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air-to-surface_missile) (AGM) or [anti-ship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-ship_missile) (AShM)? If so, what information do the tones give the pilot? Are they a way for the pilot to know which type of missile is selected?

Comment: Your question about weaponry appears off-topic on this site about aviation.

Comment: The question is not about weaponry, but about in-cockpit weapons avionics.

Comment: @CGCampbell In cockpit *weapon* avionics are still off topic because they have to do with the weapons, not with flying the plane (IMHO).

Comment: *Military Aviation* is part of *Aviation*, and this is absolutely about military aviation. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @JayCarr IMHO, I _disagree_ here. Cockpit weapons avionics, and especially the audio component used that is the question here, is wholly and completely about _flying the plane_ and _killing the Bad Guys_ while not crashing yourself.

Comment: @CGCampbell hmmmm, perhaps you have a point.  We've always had a hazy line between military topics (off topic) and military aviation topics (on topic as Ralph J correctly states).  This seems to hover right on the line.....   With your logic though, I'd agree the question should stay open.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Lock tones are normally used for (surface/air)-to-air infrared homing missiles. Air-to-surface missiles don't "growl".

The tone is used to indicate missile readiness and quality of lock, not the type. Phantom pilots in Vietnam used to cycle between all available Sidewinders to check which seeker had the best tone then put the worst one to be last in the firing order (source: "Sierra Hotel : flying Air Force fighters in the decade after Vietnam" book, page 12)

At first there was a volt-meter in the cockpit to do that, but during development testing they figured out looking inside the cockpit in a dogfight to check if the missile is ready to fire wasn't a good idea, hence the tone frequency was introduced (source: [Fox Two](http://www.donhollway.com/foxtwo/)).